# Frage über eine Übersetzung von Celan: die/der/das Wache(n)?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Ich habe in der von Pierre Joris übersetzten Sammlung von Paul-Celan-Gedichten „Breathturn Into Timestead“ die folgende Zeile gelesen (*Atemwende*, S.12):

> Dein vom Wachen stößiger Traum.

die als Folgendes übersetzt wird

> Your dream, butting from the watch.

Ich konnte „Wache“ im Duden finden, und auch in WordReference, und zwar „die Wache“ im Sinne von „watch“. Aber das steht mit „die“, was „von der Wache“ wäre.  Ich frage mich, ob hier *nicht* von Wache/watch, sondern von „wachen” gesprochen ist, d.h., dass es mit „wach sein“ oder „aufwachen“ zu tun hat. Also „vom Wachen“ —> „from waking“.  Oder irre ich mich?

Könnt Ihr mir die obenstehende Übersetzung erklären?

EDIT:

Der erster Teil des Gedichts geht so:

```
Dein vom Wachen stößiger Traum.
Mit der zwölfmal schrauben-
förmig in sein 
Horn gekerbten
Wortspur.

Der letzte Stoß, den er führt.
```

...

Comment: Ergänze bitte den Titel des Gedichts und mehr Text. Mit dieser einzelnen Zeile lässt sich nicht viel anfangen.

Comment: Das "vom" davor sagt uns, dass es ein Nomen im Singular ist. Daher hast Du in Deinem Zitat nicht das Wort "Wache", sondern "Wachen", und das ist Neutrum. Substantivierte Verben sind **immer** Neutrumg (das Essen, das Schlafen, das Blöd-in-die-Luft-Schauen, ...).

Comment: @Olifant  Ich habe so eben einige Zeilen mehr hinzugefügt.

Comment: @Olifant  Das Gedicht hat keinen Titel.

Comment: Man kann [Paul Celan : Collected verse](https://dokumen.pub/paul-celan-collected-verse.html) herunterladen. Das Gedicht ist auf Seite 536 des pdf. Zur Bedeutung von "stößig" siehe [hier](https://www.dwds.de/wb/st%C3%B6%C3%9Fig).

Comment: Ich sehe das "stößig" als etwas "gestoßenes" in dem Sinne daß der Traum eigenlich eine Geschichte beinhalten könnte, aber durch zwischenzeitiges Aufwachen immer wieder unterbrochen, also weggestoßen wird. Wenn man dieses Unterbrechen mit einem zufälligen Angriff einer Ziege vergleicht, verquirlen sich die Inhalte/Worte des Traumes halt mit den Horn des Angreifers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Für sich alleine genommen ist der Ausdruck "vom Wachen" nicht eindeutig interpretierbar. Bei "Wachen" handelt es sich jedenfalls um das substantivierte Verb "wachen". M.E. kommen bei Celans Vers zwei Interpretationen in Frage:

1. *wachen* im Sinne von *Wache stehen*, d.h. als Wachposten tätig sein  ("standing guard")
2. *wachen* im Sinne von *wach sein* ("being awake") oder ggf. *im Bett wach liegen*  ("lying awake in bed")

Was Celan "wirklich" meinte, ist nicht zu beantworten. Deshalb wird jede Übersetzung scheitern, die diese Nichteindeutigkeit nicht wiedergibt. Ob es im Englischen eine solche Übersetzung gibt, kann ich nicht beurteilen.

Ich persönlich vermute, dass Interpretation 2. die Richtige ist. Celans Posie ist oft mystisch und düster. Eine Person gleitet vom Wachsein und Grübeln in den Schlaf und träumt - wahrscheinlich nichts Angenehmes. Der Traum ist stößig, wird also mit einem gehörnten Tier verglichen, das zustößt.

Der Traum ist im Übrigen ein häufiges Motiv bei Celan. Vgl.

> [Silvana Lehmann : Reise, Tod, Traum und Melancholie - Vier Motivkreise in der Lyrik Paul Celans](https://www.grin.com/document/34952)

Diese Motivkreise sind Reise, Tod, Traum und Melancholie. Ich enpfehle einen Blick in die oben verlinkte Leseprobe.

Answer (score 3):

Da es 'vo*m* Wachen' heisst, kann nur das substativierte Verb gemeint sein, da sonst die deklination des Artikels nicht zum Genus von den Wachen (pl.) passt. Deine Vermutung ist von wörtlichen Übersetzung her zumindest richtig.

Gerade bei Gedichten muss man aber beim übersetzen auf Kontext und Konotationen achten, sodass die zitierte Übersetzung trotzdem Sinn ergeben mag:
Die Doppelbedeutung vom Verb "wachen" im Sinne von wach sein(1) als auch Wache halten ist natürlich trotzdem nicht zufällig (es ist derselbe Wortstamm), und kann in einem Gedicht auch mit beiden Bedeutungen gemeint sein. (Im Englischen hat 'watch' ja ebenso eine Doppelbedeutung mit ähnlicher Ethymologie)

Nur nur diese Zeile, die darüber hinaus nicht einmal einen ganzen Satz ergibt, kann ich ohne weiteren Kontext auch nicht zielführend interpretieren, zumal schon das nächste Wort 'stössig' auch mindestens Interpretationsbedarf hat.

(1)sicher selten so (noch) gebraucht, aber sicher so vom Ursprung her.

Comment: Danke — ich verstehe, was du meinst, aber dieser ist ein vollständiger Satz.  Ich glaube (im Moment habe ich das Buch bei mir nicht), dass der Rest des Gedichts nicht viel erklärt (Celan kann ein bisschen „geheimnisvoll“ sein)

Comment: Ein vollständiger Satz ist es nicht, weil ein Verb fehlt. Das kann natürlich gerade in Gedichten auch auftreten. Hier sehen wir grammatikalisch nur ein genauer beschriebenes Subjekt.

Answer (score 2):

Das Nomen "Wache" kann mehrere Bedeutungen haben, bei denen es auch das Genus wechseln kann:

> die Wache

Ist entweder die Tätigkeit, (herumzustehen und) auf etwas aufzupassen oder derjenige, der diese Tätigkeit ausführt, alternativ auch die Gruppe, die das tut.

> der Wache

Das ist ein substantiviertes Verbum (wachen) und bezeichnet jemanden (entweder männlichen oder unbestimmten Geschlechts, siehe "generisches Maskulinum"), der wach (im Gegensatz zu "der Schlafende" oder vielleicht auch "der Träumende") ist.

> das Wachen

Das ist dasselbe Verb ("wachen"), allerdings auf andere Art substantiviert. Es bezeichnet den Zustand, wach zu sein (im Gegensatz zu "das Schlafen", "das Träumen", ...), nicht denjenigen, der sich in diesem Zustand befindet.

Diese letzte Bedeutung ist, was Celan hier meint (wie @planetmaker ganz richtig bemerkt): der Angesprochene war (vorher) lange wach und deshalb ("vom Wachen") ist sein Traum "stößig", was immer das auch sein soll.

Ich traue mir nicht zu, Gedichte ins Englische zu übersetzen, deshalb will ich nicht beurteilen, inwieweit die Übersetzung gut ist - mir persönlich, ohne das begründen zu können, kommt sie falsch vor, aber das kann an mir und meinen mangelnden Englischkenntnissen genausogut wie an der Übersetzung liegen.